# PHP echoing variable but adding line breaks

Tags: php, variables, echo, line-breaks

I have a variable a such `$var`:

```
$var = "One, Two, Three";
```

I can `echo` the variable without any problems the output is:

```
One, Two, Three
```

Is it possible, when echoing the variable to add a `line break` where there is a `,`, so it would look like this?

```
One,
Two,
Three
```

Comment: Technically, the answer is "Yes, you can".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you echo the text to HTML, you can do the following:

```
echo str_replace(",", ", <br/>", $var);
```

If you echo the string to a console or a text file through redirection, just use the `PHP_EOL` constant, which represents the correct end-of-line string for the current platform ie. `"\n"` for Unix, `"\r\n"` for Windows:

```
echo str_replace(",", "," . PHP_EOL, $var);
```

Comment: Check the order of your arguments.

Comment: yeah, love PHP inconsistencies

Comment: and if you want to be cross-OS compatible, use `echo str_replace(",", "," . PHP_EOL, $var);` ;)

Comment: Just be careful that PHP_EOL will be the end-of-line string for the machine that executes the PHP code. If it is an HTTP server that generates a text file and sends it to the client browser, it can still cause problems if the client OS is not the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
$var = "One,\nTwo,\nThree";
```

`\n` is the line break, and makes sense if you are working through the terminal

Answer (score 2):

You use `\n` to force a new line when outputting to a terminal.

```
$var = "One,\nTwo,\nThree";
```

You can use the HTML `<br />` to output a new line on a web browser.

```
$var = "One,<br />Two,<br />Three";
```

You can use the [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function once you determine which type you want.

Comment: As I can't modify the variable (or, ideally I don't want to ) the `str_replace` looks like the best solution here but thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Make use of **`<br>`** tag

```
$var = "One, <br>Two, <br>Three";
```

<sup>(or)</sup> 
Make use of **`str_replace`** in PHP

```
<?php
$var = "One, Two, Three";
echo str_replace(',',',<br>',$var); // code replaces all your commas with , and a <br> tag
```

Answer (score 1):

Explode the string with the comma as separator, then iterate through the resulting array, adding line breaks (with the br tag if outputting to browser, or newline (\n) escape sequence if outputting to terminal) when needed?

Comment: I had considered this but wanted to see if there was an easier/ quicker solution.

Comment: @iajrz - If you're exploding the string on spaces, you could always use implode using a linebreak as the glue. It saves you having to iterate through the array again.

Comment: But that prevents any other transforms or decisions you might want to apply to each atom, which is why I chose this approach.

Comment: Sorry, iajrz - you are quite right - remiss of me, apologies.